# Extended dimensions set doesn't return data

Tags: request, google-analytics-api, no-data

I want to pull a number of metrics from Google Analytics API with "Traffic Sources", "Geo Network" and "Audience" dimensions.
So I create the following request. GA Dimensions & Metrics Explorer shows that these metrics & dimensions are compatible. But for some reason, this request returns zero values:

```
 {
  "reportRequests": [
    {
      "viewId": "xxxxxxxx",
      "dateRanges": [
        {
          "startDate": "2020-03-01",
          "endDate": "2020-03-11"
        }
      ],
      "metrics": [
        {
          "expression": "ga:sessions"
        },
        {
          "expression": "ga:newUsers"
        },
        {
          "expression": "ga:transactions"
        },
        {
          "expression": "ga:transactionRevenue"
        }
      ],
      "dimensions": [
        {
          "name": "ga:date"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:campaign"
        },          
        {
          "name": "ga:sourceMedium"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:country"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:region"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:city"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:userAgeBracket"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:userGender"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:interestInMarketCategory"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Although restricted dimensions set shows that data exists:

```
      "dimensions": [
        {
          "name": "ga:date"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:campaign"
        },          
        {
          "name": "ga:sourceMedium"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:country"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:region"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:city"
        }
```

Why extended dimensions set that shown in 1st example doesn't return data?

Thanks in advance!
Eugene

Answer (score 0):

May be GA doesnot have any information about the user age, gender and in-Market segment (ga:interestInMarketCategory). So when you add these dimensions with others, API returns data for the combination of specified dimensions.

So let's say there are 20 sessions from combination of city = x and region = y. But when you add gender to it, no combination can be made (e.g. city = x and region = y and gender = ?), hence API will return zero response.